# Get connected devices to my Wi-Fi network (andriod)

Tags: python, networking, wifi

I am trying to write a python script to get all the devices connected to my network, and I want to also add the ability to kick off the unwanted devices from my network, I started with this code to scan my network but It keeps giving me this error, and I could not figure out the reason of the error.
[image]

here is the error
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to unpack the `client` object too many times. Perhaps what you mean to do is this:

```
ans, unans = scapy.srp(packet, timeout=3, verbose=0)

for snd, rcv in ans:
  print(f"{rcv.psrc}" + " "* 18 + f"{rcv.hwsrc}")
```

Here's the reference from `scapy` [documentation](https://scapy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/extending.html?highlight=srp#more-examples).